# ASP.Net Core MVC EF - как задать имена столбцов таблиц только для представлений

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, view, атрибуты

У меня есть классы для работы с БД (CodeFirst) и я знаю, что могу задать аттрибутом [Column("Name")] специфическое имя для создания столбца в БД, но есть ли какая-то возможность обозначить название стоблца для генерации кода с помощью html-helper'ов и подобного во View (а в БД останутся стандартное название от именя поля класса)

Comment: вам нужен атрибут [DisplayName](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/775220/asp-net-mvc-what-are-the-uses-of-display-displayna)

Comment: как Выше уже написали Вам поможет атрибут `[DisplayName("Имя столбца в представлении")]` и метод `DisplayNameFor(x=>x.Name)`

Comment: И никто так и не захотел ответом оформить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

то о чем Вы спрашиваете легко решается использованием атрибута [DisplayName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.displaynameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

Применяете данный атрибут к вашему свойству в модели, и при помощи *хелпера* [DisplayNameFor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.displaynameextensions.displaynamefor(v=vs.118).aspx) в представлении вы получите имя поля заданное в атрибуте `DisplayName`

---

Модель

```
[DisplayName("Стоимость")]
public decimal Price {get;set;}
```

Представление

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model=>model.Price)
```

в 2015 студии результат будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
<label class="control=label">Стоимость</label>
```